# Codewars Python (list index out of range)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with python, and programming overall.
I'm trying to solve a puzzle that goes like this:

> The marketing team is spending way too much time typing in hashtags.
>   Let's help them with our own Hashtag Generator! 
>   Here's the deal:
>
> It must start with a hashtag (#).
>
> All words must have their first letter capitalized.
>
> If the final result is longer than 140 chars it must return false.
>
> If the input or the result is an empty string it must return false.

As a beginner, i came up with this solution, it's really crappy, but it does the work.

```
def generate_hashtag(s):

while '  ' in s:
    s = s.replace('  ', ' ')

count = 0
arr = []
for char in s:
    arr.append(char)
    count += 1

arr.insert(0, '#')

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    arr[i] = arr[i].lower()

if s == '':
    return False
if count > 140:
    return False

arr[1] = arr[1].upper()


i = 0
for char in arr:
    if char.isspace():
        del arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[i].upper()
    i += 1

return ''.join(arr)
```

> print(generate_hashtag("Codewars        is            Nice"))
>
> ### CodewarsIsNice
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

It works, solves all the tasks, but gives an error on CodeWars:

*File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 29, in generate_hashtag
arr[i] = arr[i].upper()
IndexError: list index out of range*

**It works perfectly on my computer, but i cant submit it on CodeWars because of this error.
Can anyone help me out?**

Comment: Did you try using a string that ends in a space?

Comment: I'm using 3.8 on my system, 3.6 on CodeWars

Comment: Thank you Sayse, didn't think of that, gonna try to solve it, that gives the error :D

Comment: to change to lower you don't need loop but only `arr = arr.lower()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original solution fails if the input ends with whitespace. The offending code:

```
i = 0
for char in arr:
    if char.isspace():
        del arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[i].upper()
    i += 1
```

It's never a good idea to iterate over a collection, while changing the size of that collection at the same time. If the last character is whitespace, you delete it. Then, you immediately try to access an index which no longer exists, because you just deleted it.

Alternative:

```
def generate_hashtag(string):
    hashtag = "".join(string.title().split())
    return [False, f"#{hashtag}"][bool(string and 0 < len(hashtag) <= 140)]
```

Answer (score 0):

ended up doing this lmao, it removes all whitespaces at the end, but it's kinda dumb to convert it back to string, remove, clear array and make it an array again :D.

If anyone knows any better solution, lmk

```
temp = ''.join(arr)
    temp = temp.rstrip()
    arr.clear()
    for char in temp:
        arr.append(char)
```

Comment: You could have just added `s = s.strip()` as the first line of your existing function 

Answer (score 0):

```
In [37]: def generate_hashtag(hashtag):
    ...:     if not hashtag or not hashtag.strip():
    ...:         return False
    ...:     if hashtag.startswith("#"):
    ...:         hashtag = hashtag[1:]
    ...:     hashtag = '#'+''.join([word.capitalize() for word in hashtag.split()])
    ...:     return hashtag if len(hashtag)<=140 else False
    ...: 

In [38]: generate_hashtag("brothers for life")
Out[38]: '#BrothersForLife'
```

Comment: You're not catching the proper length. The **final** length must not be more than 140. Also, the output should not contain spaces. Downvoted until fixed

Comment: Hey @LukasThaler, thanks for outlining that. Check the updated code.

Comment: I think the function should return `False` if you call it with a string containing only spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```html
def generate_hashtag(s):
    result="#"+ str(s.title().replace(' ',''))
    return s and not len(result)>140 and result or False
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!